# Wait for object loading in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can i manipulate data in my another component, when i assign data from service. My view can read this data asynchronously but i can not read property via `console.log`. Every time i see 'undefined'. I need to load another route/component and back to an earlier view, after this `console.log`
 displaying my request. Here is my code:
Frienddetails.component.ts

```
   export class FrienddetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      name: string;
      id: number;
      gameId: any = [];
      serviceArray: any = [];
      objectDataService: any = [];
      objectDataArray: any = [];

      constructor(public dataService: DataService,
        public friendService: FriendService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
          this.name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
          this.serviceArray = this.dataService.getDataService();

      }

      fetchListOfMatch(query) {
        this.friendService.getListOfMatch(query).subscribe((data) => {
          this.objectDataArray.push(data.matches.length);
        });
      }

      getMatchGameId() {
        for (let i of this.objectDataArray) {
          let k = i.matches.length;
          for (let c = 0; c < k; c++) {
            this.gameId.push(i.matches[c].gameId);
          }
        }
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.serviceArray);
        this.id = this.friendService.getIdByName(this.name, this.serviceArray);
        this.friendService.id = this.id;
        this.friendService.query = `${this.friendService.apiUrl}${this.friendService.id}?season=11&${this.friendService.apikey}`;
        this.fetchListOfMatch(this.friendService.query);
      }
    }
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  friends= FRIEND;
  myDataFromDb: any[] = [];
  SortedArray: any[] = [];
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
}

  private getDataFromDb(query) {
   /* function compare(a,b) {
      if (a.id < b.id)
        return -1;
      if (a.id > b.id)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }*/
      this.dataService.getData(query).subscribe((data) =>
      {




       this.dataService.data.push(data);
       this.dataService.serviceResponse = data;
      });
    }

  ngOnInit() {

    for (let i of this.dataService.friends) {
        this.dataService.query = `${this.dataService.apiUrl}${i.nick}?${this.dataService.apikey}`;

        this.getDataFromDb(this.dataService.query);

      }




        }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You certainly can log the data in the console; move your console.log statement inside of the callback for the subscribe.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer i edited my question. Look at app.component.ts. Here is subscription of my request. I want to get this data in my FrienddetailComponent where i make another http request - now for specified player.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to add an ngOnChanges lifecycle hook to the FrienddetailComponent which can check to see if it has a valid input and make an additional service request accordingly.

Add an `@Input` to the FrienddetailsComponent and pass in the expected value from AppComponent.

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. However, i do not think so that ngOnChanges will solve my problem. Because as you can see in my question (FrienddetailsComponent code) i need to do another http

Comment: You can do an http call from ngOnChanges... just inject your data service into the child component